# Relations in tensor product of vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

From the definition of [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Definition), we have $V\otimes W=F(V\times W)/R$.

Now, I understand $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w=v_1\otimes w+v_2\otimes w$, because the left-side is $(v_1+v_2,w)+R$, and the right-side is $(v_1,w)+R+(v_2+w)+R=(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)+R$, and we know that $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)-(v_1+v_2,w)\in R$.

But what about $cv\otimes w=c(v\otimes w$)? The left-side is $(cv,w)+R$ and the right is $c((v,w)+R)$. Why can we say the two sides are the same?

**Edit**: For the two sides to be the same, we would need to be able to say $cR=R$, don't we? This point is what I don't understand, and hasn't been answered in comment/answer so far.

Comment: (you define R precisely so that you get these relations you want)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki 
 
Maybe I wasn't clear about my question. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $R$ is by definition generated by the terms of the form $$ (v_{1}+v_{2}, w) - (v_{1}, w)- (v_{2}, w)$$ $$(cv,w)-c(v,w)$$ $$(w, v_{1}+v_{2}) - (w, v_{1})- (w, v_{2})$$ $$(v,cw)-c(v,w)$$

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: $c[(v,w)+R]$ is defined to be $c(v,w)+R$, not $c(v,w)+cR$